# Hi, i want mvn to download one dependency from a particular URl. How can i do that?

Tags: maven

Hi I am using Spring boot and I am trying resolve one dependency. All I want to do is to tell maven that download that dependency from that particular URL.

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>group-a</groupId>
          <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the URL a Maven repository? If so, add it as `<repository>`.

If not, download the dependency and place it in your company Nexus/Artifactory (if you have one).

If you work locally, you can also install it into your local repository (with `install:install-file`).